# c++ access violation writing exception on stack

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I try to program an UPN Calculator in c++ with console input.
So I wrote a node and a stack class and use it in the main class. When starting everything goes well until I start pushing stuff on to the stack. I then get a "Access violation writing exception" and do not really understand what the problem is.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Node.h"


Node::Node(int value){this->value = value;}

int Node::GetValue(){return this->value;}

Node * Node::GetNode(){return this;}

Node* Node::GetNextNode(){return this->next_node;}

bool Node::SetNextNode(Node n)
{
        this->next_node = &n;
        return true;

}

Node * Node::GetBeforeNode(){return this->before_node;}

bool Node::SetBeforeNode(Node n)
{
        this->before_node = &n; // <---- the error occures here
        return true;
}
```

Comment: `n` will be gone once the function returns, all pointers to it are dangling.

Comment: ... because the `Node n` is passed by value. You probably want to pas it by reference (if mandatory) or pointer (if optional).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create pointers to variables with local scopes.

Your `Node n` is passed to `SetBeforeNode` by value, so it's copied, you take it's address, but then `n` goes out of scope and you stay with dangling pointer, so instead of:

```
bool Node::SetBeforeNode(Node n)
```

it should be:

```
bool Node::SetBeforeNode(const Node& n)
```